# MySQL count with parameters

Tags: mysql

i have MySQL table like this

```
ID  |user_id    |type   |extra
---------------------------------------------
1   |1          |1      |0
2   |2          |1      |0
3   |2          |1      |2
4   |1          |1      |2
5   |1          |2      |0
6   |1          |1      |2
7   |2          |2      |2
8   |3          |1      |0
9   |2          |2      |2
10  |2          |2      |0
```

I need to count it by user_id to get output like:

```
user_id |one_noextra    |one_twoextra   |two_noextra    |two_twoextra
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |1              |2              |1              |0
2       |1              |1              |1              |2
3       |1              |0              |0              |0
```

(I don't know, if I counted it right, but I hope you get the point.)

Is there any way to achieve this in MySQL?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a limit on how many extra/types you can have?

Comment: There is, 1-4 in **type** and 0-2 in **extra**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viewing your sample dataset if `type,extra` are limited i.e type can only have (1,2) and extra can only have (0,2) you can do so,using expression in sum it will result as 0 or 1 based on the outcome of the expression and you can have your count accordingly

```
SELECT 
user_id,
SUM(`type`=1 AND  `extra`=0) one_noextra,
SUM(`type`=1 AND  `extra`=2) one_twoextra,
SUM(`type`=2 AND  `extra`=0) two_noextra,
SUM(`type`=2 AND  `extra`=2) two_twoextra
FROM Table1
GROUP BY user_id
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf3c/5)

Comment: I have more values, but I'll just alter it. Thank you very much.