# (Columns) Group into one, count into two

Tags: mysql

How could I construct a query which is grouped by one column `group_id`, but counted into two columns?

I have the following table.

```
---------------------
 user_id  | group_id
---------------------
 1        | 6
 0        | 6
 0        | 6
 2        | 8
 3        | 8
 0        | 7
 4        | 9
```

I wish for the results to display like this. Below, the conditions would be `count_users` is those with a `user_id` greater than but not equal to 0, and `count_guests` would be those where the `user_id` is equal to 0.

```
---------------------------------------
 group_id | count_users | count_guests
---------------------------------------
 6        | 1            | 2
 8        | 2            | 0
 7        | 0            | 1
 9        | 1            | 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL count with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224392/mysql-count-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MySQL uses 1 for true and 0 for false you can use:

```
SELECT
    group_id,
    SUM(user_id > 0) as count_users,
    SUM(user_id = 0) as count_guests
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    group_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775d69/1)